# How to locate a domain controller on a Windows network when not a member?

Tags: active-directory

Is there a way to determine which machine on an active directory network is the domain controller, if on a computer not logged on to the domain? This is for a penetration test, going in blind.

I've tried looking up the domain (which I know the name of) in `nslookup`, after setting `type` to `all` and running `_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.Active_Directory_domain_name`

I also tried `dsdomroleinfo` and `enumdomains` with rpcclient on machines that allowed null sessions.

Is there any easy way to look this up without resorting to sniffing?

Comment: Afaik most smb client can say this with a simple ask. Linux, samba are your keywords. smbclient -N -L a.b.c.d

Answer (score 5):

## Try type "any" or "SRV"

Did you query for the ["`any`" DNS resource record (wildcard/pseudo) type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#Other_types_and_pseudo_resource_records)? (Otherwise the default is to simple query for `A` records. And the records in question are in fact `SRV` RRs.)

(Also: you said you used type "all", I don't know if there is such a thing. What `any` does is translate to a query for [resource record type `0x00FF`, decimal 255](https://archive.is/MmyOa#selection-3365.0-3385.1). I checked with Wireshark. This translation is done by your client. I don't know all clients, but I can tell you that `dig` does NOT know of "type all" and NOT "type *" either and will give you an error. But dig will work nicely if you say "-t any".)

Using `dig` (if "example.com" is your Active Directory domain name):

```
dig _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.EXAMPLE.COM -t any
dig _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.EXAMPLE.COM -t srv
```

Using the WINDOWS version of `nslookup`, the type MUST go as first parameter like so:

```
nslookup -type=any _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.EXAMPLE.COM
nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.EXAMPLE.COM
```

### Also try just the regular "A" type

Also you can simply dig/nslookup the `Active_Directory_DNS_domain_name` and this will give you DC-IPs. (Because there's actually `A` records at that level.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside the network, then most likely the DNS server that DHCP assigned to you is a domain controller. If you are using nslookup from outside the network, then you should not be able to look up the domain controller; that information should be only available internally.

Comment: Initial validation will be scanning for servers listening in tcp ports: 389, 636, 3268 or 3269. Then if you know the domain try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/153526/how-can-i-find-the-ldap-server-in-the-dns-on-windows